# "invalid expression" running gnuplot in bash script

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I am running this program SCRIPT.sh,

```
#!/bin/bash 
FFT_FILE="$(find . -type f -iname "HR*.fft")" 
FFT_FILE1=$FFT_FILE".GNUPLOT" 
od -f -v -w8 $FFT_FILE > $FFT_FILE1 
gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker 
    reset 
    set term postscript enh 
    set out 'FFT_1.ps' 
    set xlabel 'Frequency (Hz)' 
    set key box 
    filename="$FFT_FILE1" 
    stats filename nooutput
    max_row = STATS_records 
    plot [(1000.0/4880.0):(1000.0/59.0)] filename u ($0/(max_row*81.92e-6)):(sqrt(($2*$2)+($3*$3))) w l lw 3 title "FFT"
    reset
EOFMarker
```

but the output comes as

```
gnuplot> plot [(1000.0/4880.0):(1000.0/59.0)] filename u (./SCRIPT.sh/(max_row*81.92e-6)):(sqrt((*)+(*))) w l lw 3 title "FFT"
                                                           ^
    line 0: invalid expression
```

May I request for detailed explanation and help regarding this situation?

The ["HR*.fft"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tr_sMzwn99bsYjYCBJXnRb8q-otWxm66/view?usp=sharing) file contains the results of Fast Fourier Transform from [PRESTO](https://www.cv.nrao.edu/%7Esransom/presto/) in binary.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Thank you for this information. I have arranged my codeblocks properly.

Comment: You use $0 in your here document. This is replaced with the filename of the script. You have to quote the heredoc marker. https://serverfault.com/questions/399428/how-do-you-escape-characters-in-heredoc

Comment: You use $0 in your here document. This is replaced with the filename of the script. You have to quote the heredoc marker. https://serverfault.com/questions/399428/how-do-you-escape-characters-in-heredoc or if you want to mix just escape the $0 as `\$0`

Comment: ... or use `column(0)` instead of `$0`

Comment: I see. The code is actually working right now, and the plot has formed. Thanks to all of you for these information.